# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>' in ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, try-catch

Hi i have the following method that i am trying to use

```
sendrequest(req: connreq) {
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.firereq.child(req.recipient).push({
  sender: req.sender
  }).then(() => {
    resolve({ success: true });
    }).catch((error) => {
      resolve(error);
})
})
return promise;  
}
```

But my visual studio code gives me the following error

```
Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'
```

I am using ionic to compile this program and i am unsure on how to correct this method. My tutorial is in ionic 3 so it may be old and i am not sure how to alter it to fit in to the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! To convert something from a promise-like thing to a real promise, just use [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```
sendrequest(req: connreq) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.firereq.child(req.recipient).push({
    sender: req.sender
  }));
}
```